# Angular 2/5 - Frequently used Modules and refresh in lazy loading

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

First of all i already read the whole tutorial of angular (angular.io). And i understand the concept of lazy loading. But i have some further questions depending on how to handle some issues. First one is why i can´t use angular materials in components which i load by lazy loading?

So for my understanding I import packages (for example Angular Material) in app.module.ts:

```
import { MaterialAppModule } from './shared/materials.module';

@NgModule({
   imports: [
      MaterialAppModule //own Module which keeps all Material Moduls
   ]
})
```

It works for all Modules which i load not with lazy loading. If use a routerlink and navigate to a module which is lazy loaded all buttons for example are still ugly without any fancy material stuff. I fixed that by importing angular material to the module. But the impact is that i load every time angular material classes again. But in AOT the code is transferred to Javascript, Html and CSS. So the required code is there. Is there any solution to give modules, which are loaded by lazy loading, the information where are already loaded packages to use them for the components?

Second question is much smaller. The constructer and Ngoninit are methods which are used only on first load. Is there any method which is triggered every time if I navigate to this component?
For example i wants to count inside of the component to which i navigate how many times it was called.

Comment: hello, i think that you have to import your shared module in all lazy loaded modules to use it and not in the app.module.ts, i have a shared module here that contain shared components and services and i'm importing it in lazy loaded modules where i need it. for your second question you can use a shared service to store that information, each time you navigate to that componenet you call that method to increment count. you can user ngrx store for state management too for advanced cases

Comment: @FatehMohamed Tahnk you for your answer. Currently I do the same with shared module. But my issue is that i reload the same information again and again. I edit my second question asap for more details :)

Comment: well for the shared module , i'm afraid it is the only solution, i'm working on a project with more than 10 lazy loaded modules and i've tried everything, the only solution is to import your shared module when you need it in your lazy loaded module and if you want to have a single instance of a service between all these modules you can use singletons by returning a ModuleWithProviders object and import your module like this: sharedModule.forRoot(). check this bro https://alligator.io/angular/providers-shared-modules/

Answer (score 0):

For your second question, Angular Lifecycle hooks can be used, there is ngOnchanges lifecycle hook is used to trigger everytime / DoCheck, also you can refer following conversation for not calling any methods on navigation.
You can provide your code so that we can understand more.

[LifeCycle calls are not called on router navigation](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8012)